# Let inner function use arguments of outer function

Tags: r, function, nested

I'm having trouble finding out the following: There's an `outer` function inside which an `inner` function is called. The `inner` function is recursive. Both functions share some common arguments `a`, `b`, `c`, as I want the `outer` function to pass these arguments through to `inner`. `a`, `b`, `c` are essentially option parameters for `inner`, which need to be accessible from outside.

A drastically simplified version could look like this

```r
inner <- function(a, b, c, d, i = 0) {
  # Something
  inner(a = left, b = right, c, d, i = i + 1)
}

outer <- function(a, b, c, r, t) {
  d <- r^2
  inner(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d)
}
```

Now, the call of `inner` inside `outer` seems a bit bulky to me. I'd like `a`, `b`, `c` to be passed to `inner` "automatically" instead of having to explicitly passing them as arguments again, since they are constant option parameters. The key may be ellipsis/... but unfortunately I couldn't manage to find the answer ...

Help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Define the inner function inside the outer function and the inner function will have access to the outer function's variables.  Here `inner` uses `a` from `outer` even though `a` was not passed to `inner`.

```
outer <- function(a, x) {
  inner <- function(y) {
    a + y
  }

  inner(2 * x)
}

# test
outer(10, 100)
## [1] 210
```

**2)** Alternately, inject `inner` into `outer` like this:

```
inner <- function(y) {
  a + y
}

outer <- function(a, x) {
  environment(inner) <- environment()    
  inner(2 * x)
}

# test
outer(10, 100)
## [1] 210
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to write

```
outer <- function(r, t, ...) {
  d <- r^2
  inner(d = d, ...)
}
```

Passing values for `a`, `b`, and `c` to `outer` will cause these to get automatically passed to the inner function.  The only drawback to this method is that it's not clear from the `outer` function that values for `a`, `b`, and `c` are required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The drawback you mentioned is exactly why I couldn't use that approach ...